# How does the ASIC Jalepeno connect to the Internet?

Tags: asic

Does the ASIC Jalepeno miner need to be connected via USB for it to work properly (to access the Internet)?

I was hoping there was a wi-fi setup option but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be plugged it to the USB looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The ASIC does nothing on its own - it is just hardware without any logic.

You need to plug it into USB and run a mining software (like cgminer) on the PC where the ASIC is connected to via USB.